# How can I reset another element using another button

Tags: javascript, html

I have an onclick function which I want to be able to press to reset another HTML element (in this case a button id)

```js
function reset(button) {
  button.id = "1";

  document.getElementById("button.id").innerHTML = button.id;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- close button -->
<button class="btn btn-secondary" onClick="reset();" data-dismiss="modal">
    Close
</button>
<!-- close button end -->

<!-- add to cart button -->
<button type="button" onClick="add_price(this); add_image(this);/*reset(this)*/ ;" id="1" class="addtocart btn-primary">
    Add to cart
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus ml-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
<!-- add to cart button end -->
```

the `/*reset(this)*/` works but not enough since it reset every time I add an item to my shopping cart. I want the id to reset when I exit my modal using to close button (the first button) in this case.

Is there any way to use `reset("button.id")` to reset the add to cart button? or something alike?

Comment: show your js code

Comment: What does it meant to you to "reset" an element? BTW, You are unlikely to have an element with an id of `"button.id"`; you probably meant `document.getElementById(button.id).innerHTML = button.id;`...

Comment: the code works, on the add to cart button. but i want the reset button like binded to the other button. so that i reset he add price and add image functions with the close button press instead of the add to cart button press

Comment: Your Javascript is taking the button you just clicked, setting its id to "1", then you're selecting another button with with the id "button.id". and setting its html to "1".  To select your "Add to cart" button from the `reset()` function, you need to select it with `document.getElementById('1')` or `document.getElementByClassName('addtocart')`. You can then reset it's ID as I showed you in my answer... but if you change it's ID, you need to keep track of it so you know what element to select in `reset()`.

Answer (score 1):

Via JQuery:

`$('.btn-secondary').attr('id', 'newID')`

Via Javascript

`document.getElementByClassName(".btn-secondary").id = "newid";`

Comment: the code works, on the add to cart button. but i want the reset button like binded to the other button. so that i reset he add price and add image functions with the close button press instead of the add to cart button press

Comment: @Solflingan You'll need a way to select the specific button, whether adding a unique class or id to the button. Then you can select it by class: `$('.your-class')` or id: `$('#your-id')`.  It looks like your close button has the classes "btn btn-secondary". You could select the close button with those classes (if it is unique to that button).  If you're using bootstrap modal, you can get a onClose event like so `$("#yourModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) { // your code here });`